# XSL-FO foreach new line in node

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

How can I output the content of an xml node in xsl-fo whilst splitting it by a delimiter (in this case, a new line)?

**XML:**

```
<node>
    <text>text1
text2
text3
text4</text>
</node>
```

How can I display (or loop through) each new line in the  node?

Ideally I would like each wrapped in a block.

**Output:**

```
<fo:block>text1</fo:block>
<fo:block>text2</fo:block>
<fo:block>text3</fo:block>
<fo:block>text4</fo:block>
```

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 use `tokenize()`, in XSLT 1.0 you'd have to write a tail-recursive template, or use a pre-written one like http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html - the question I've marked as a duplicate shows these options based on splitting at `,`, you can use the same technique splitting at `&#10;`

Comment: The namespace required http://exslt.org/strings does not exist

Comment: Plus creating nodes 'token' doesn't seem to work with renderX, (or maybe xslfo):  `Element 'token' belonging to the anonymous namespace cannot occur in an XSL-FO document outside 'instream-foreign-object' elements`

Comment: Please take some time to read _all_ of Ian's answer. He has already told you that you need to write a recursive template if EXSLT is not supported.